# Undefined Boost symbol when linking to pre-compiled QuantLib binaries on MacOS

Tags: macos, c++11, boost, apple-m1, quantlib

I am trying to compile some C++ that depends on QuantLib, which in turn depends on Boost.  I am working on a MacBook Pro M1 (ARM architecture).  I installed Boost and QuantLib using the instructions on this page: https://www.quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml.  I then tried to compile the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
 
int main(int, char*[])
{
    QuantLib::Option::Type OptionType(QuantLib::Option::Call);
    std::cout << "Option Type = " << OptionType << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

using the following command:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 ql_ex1.cpp -o build/ql_ex1 $(INC) $(LIB) \
    -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/quantlib/1.23/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include \
    -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/quantlib/1.23/lib
```

This gave me the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "boost::assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, char const*, long)", referenced from:
      long double boost::math::detail::sinpx<long double>(long double) in ql_ex1-044d3e.o
  "boost::assertion_failed_msg(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, long)", referenced from:
      boost::array<long double, 171ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const in ql_ex1-044d3e.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

So far I have tried the following approaches,

- Install x86 binaries and run `clang++` in emulation.  I see the same Undefined symbols error.
- Try to identify a Boost shared library file that I need to link to.  I have not been able to find anything that contains the `assertion_failed` symbol.

Can someone point me to where (if anywhere) this symbol is defined?  It would be useful to know if I am just missing the right compiler options or whether there is a more fundamental issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a `-lQuantLib` in your command line?  You're telling the compiler where to look for the libraries (the `-L` switches`) but not which libraries to link.

Also, check whether homebrew also installed a `quantlib-config` script on your computer.  If so, it should provide the switches you need; try running

```
quantlib-config --cflags
```

which should output the `-I` flags specifying the location of the QuantLib headers (and possibly the `-std=c++11` flag you're passing manually), and

```
quantlib-config --libs
```

which should output the corresponding `-L` switches as well as the `-lQuantLib` you missed.

If they work, you can use the command

```
clang++ ql_ex1.cpp -o build/ql_ex1 $(INC) $(LIB) \
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include \
`quantlib-config --cflags` `quantlib-config --libs`
```

and let the script fill in the info for you.